# Default values in array mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to make default values for array in mogoose schema:

```
warning:
 type: Array
 default: [10, 50, 99]
```

Am I right in such decision or there is some other way to do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Regarding to the Mongoose-Documentation, your way is correct.

Here a small example:

```
var arrayTestSchema = new Schema({
    anArray: {
      type: Array,
      'default': [1, 2, 3]
    }
});
```

And a link to the related documentation page: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/defaults.html

Answer (score 11):

**for Mongoose v5.x**

If you want to specify the type of the array child, you can define it like example below:

```js
const BlogSchema = new Schema({
  tags: {
    type: [String],
    default: ["tech", "economy"],
  },
})
```

or

```js
const BlogSchema = new Schema({
  tags: {
    type: [
      {
        type: String,
        // Another properties
      },
    ],
    default: ["tech", "economy"],
  },
})
```

---

**References:**

- https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays

Answer (score 2):

It should be a json, I don't know what is what you posted there.

new Schema({
    warning: { type: Array, default: [10, 50, 99] }
   })

Comment: Oh yeah,I thought it was dead, nobody talks about it anymore :)